# Finding a particular parent of an HTML DOM element

Tags: jquery, dom, traversal

Lets say I have the following:

```
<table><tr><td>
    <table> <!-- I want a reference to this table -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr><td><span class="theSpanClass"></span></td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
</td></tr></table>
```

Using jQuery, I'd like to be able to reference the 2nd table starting from the span towards the body.

Thanks

Comment: What are you asking? Are you trying to find the outermost `table` parent of an element?

Comment: With your **updated** question, that's no longer the *outer-most* table.

Comment: Yes, sorry and thanks everyone, from the answers I figured out I asked incorrectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For original question:** If you're coming from the span, then you can do this:

```
$(".theSpanClass").parents("table:last")
```

This uses [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) to get all ancestors that are `<table>`, then selects the [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) one it finds, since they're ordered going *up* the DOM.

---

**Updated for new question:** Since the question's been updated, that's 2 levels up, which you would find using [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) like this:

```
$(".theSpanClass").parents("table:eq(1)") //it's 0-based
```